# data from plost.time_hist does not match the data from the DF

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I try create plost.time_hist on streamlit dashboard, but the data from the graph does not match the data from the dataframe

python code:

```
df_t = df[['issue', 'created', 'created_hour', 'created_dayweek', 'to_reaction_expired_percent', 'is_sla_reaction_expired', 'is_sla_resolve_expired',
                 'reaction_author']]
    st.write(df_t)
    plost.time_hist(df_t, date='created', x_unit='hours', y_unit='day', aggregate='count')
```

'created' - datetime64[ns]

But hours and week days in time_hist not match dataframe data
[image]

try to change x_unit and y_unit, filters but this did not give any result